# JProfiler - not detecting jvm run by different user

Tags: java, profiling, jprofiler

I am trying profiling (using jprofiler) an application running in tomcat in linux machine. The tomcat is running with different user account, and i don't have access to that tomcat account. I am trying to run the jprofiler with my user account. But Jprofiler is not detecting the jvm which is used by tomcat.

Is there way to detect the jvm which runs using different user account than the jprofiler?

I appreciate any helps. Thanks

Comment: What version of JProfiler are you using and what JVM is your Tomcat installation using?  From the [JProfiler documentation](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/help.pdf) it seems JVM 1.6 is required to make use of this feature.

Comment: Can you share your start up script for tomcat? Are you sure the debug hooks have been added to the line that launches the JRE?

Answer (score 2):

Attaching to running processes is generally only possible if the other process runs with the same user account.

JProfiler has a feature to profile Windows services that run with the local system account, but on Linux, the only choice is to su to the appropriate user.

Of course you can always use the integration wizard (Session->Integration Wizards->New Server integration) to modify the Tomcat start script.

Comment: Thanks Kegal, our tomcat env is some complex(not like regular single folder extract, but installed using yum, and distributed to multiple directories, startup script is customized). So we chosen su option, our admin guy provided permission to switch to tomcat account. From tomcat account, running jpenable helped to attach the app to jprofiler GUI.  Thanks to all